# PHP While loop, echo Issues

Tags: php, while-loop

There has to be a easier way...
I keep getting this for the second line.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("'$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords";
          "(\"";
          $row['longitude'];
          ",";
          $row['latitude'];
          ",\"";
          $row['routername'];
          "-";
          $row['desc'];
          "\", \"";
          $row['routername'];
          "-";
          $row['desc'];
          "<br><a href=\"./div/";
          $row['routername'];
          "\">Site Info</a>'");
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Replace all of those `;`s with `.`s and see if that works.

Comment: @mrlayance This is a trivial case of a syntax error. You shouldn't post such questions here. I understand you might not have a lot of experience with PHP but you should first consult a manual or do a fast Google search. This is why you are getting -1s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to combine with a `.` and not with `;`

```
echo ("'$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords" . 
      "(\"" .
      $row['longitude'] .
      ....
```

Have a look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 2):

Most of the `;` should be `.` if you are attempting to concatenate these strings:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("'$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords" .
          "(\"" .
          $row['longitude'] .
          "," .
          $row['latitude'] .
          ",\"" .
          $row['routername'] .
          "-" .
          $row['desc'] .
          "\", \"" .
          $row['routername'] .
          "-" .
          $row['desc'] .
          "<br><a href=\"./Ldiv/" .
          $row['routername'].
          "\">Site Info</a>'"); // Here's the actual end of the statement
    echo "<br />";
}
```

This woudl be a lot tidier with a HEREDOC:

```
echo <<<ROW
$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords(
   {$row['longitude']},
   {$row['latitude']},
   "{$row['routername']}-{$row['desc']}",
   "$row['routername']}-{$row['desc']}"<br>
    <a href="./Ldiv/{$row['routername']}">Site Info</a>
)

ROW;
```

Although , it looks like something is missing before the `<br>` since the previous quote doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong for what you are trying to execute.

The `;` in PHP is an end statement, essentially. You are telling PHP to stop executing the echo on the very first line `echo ("'$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords" ;` which is NOT what you want.

Instead, replace all the `;` with `.`'s except for the last echo statement

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "'$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords" .
      "(\"" .
      $row['longitude'] .
      "," .
      $row['latitude'] .
      ",\"" .
      $row['routername'] .
      "-" .
      $row['desc'] .
      "\", \"" .
      $row['routername'] .
      "-" .
      $row['desc'] .
      "<br><a href=\"./Ldiv/" .
      $row['routername']; .
      "\">Site Info</a>'";
echo "<br />";
```

}